# Gtk assert fail c gtk_calendar

Tags: c, gtk, assert, glib

I've a assertion fail with my gtk+/C code, so, I don't know why :

The error is : g_date_set_month: assertion 'g_date_valid_month (m)' failed

And the suspected lines are:

```
t_day day; 
uint y, m, da;

gtk_calendar_get_date(GTK_CALENDAR(d->calendar), &y, &m, &da);

g_date_set_day(&day.date, da);
g_date_set_year(&day.date, y);
g_date_set_month(&day.date, m);
```

it's the only function which I use g_date_set_month().

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GtkCalendar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCalendar.html#gtk-calendar-get-date) returns a month value between 0-11:

> month : location to store the month number (between 0 and 11), or
>   NULL. [out][allow-none]

GDate uses month values between 1-12 (see the [internal representation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#GDate) and the [enum type](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#GDateMonth) used in the setter):

> guint month : 4; the day of the day-month-year representation of the
>   date, as a number between 1 and 12

You will presumably need to convert between the two formats.